# Selenium 2 - Javascript Alert triggered by Back button blocks driver.navigate().back()

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to handle a javascript alert which is triggered when the back button is pressed.  i.e.:

1. Go to our site
2. Click back
3. Javascript alert will pop up
4. Dismiss alert

   I implemented a test which works fine in firefox but in Internet Explorer (7), the driver.navigate.back() method blocks until the alert is manually removed.

   Has anyone come across this before?  Any hints would be highly appreciated :)

   I am using RemoteWebDriver for this test.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RemoteWebDriver you can use the RemoteTargetLocator inner class, it implements methods to handle alerts:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept()
```

Comment: I cannot do that because the code blocks when the the back button has been pressed. However, I managed to work around it by executing `driver.executeScript("javascript: setTimeout(\"history.go(-1)\", 2000)");`  instead of navigate().back()

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by sending the following javascript command instead of using navigate().back():

```
driver.executeScript(javascript: setTimeout(\"history.go(-1)\", 2000));
```